# PHP looking for wrong library file, apt seems to have wrong version installed, but I can't remove it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, libraries, apt

I had a LAMP stack with libsodium working fine on Ubuntu 15.x but after upgrade to 16.04, PHP and libsodium don't work together

```
$> php -dextension=libsodium.so -r 'echo "foo";'
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/libsodium.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/libsodium.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Note that the number in the path here does not match `20151012`

```
$> find /usr/lib | grep sodium
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/libsodium.so
```

Remove and reinstall maybe?

```
 $> apt-get purge 'libsodium*
 [ok]
 $> dpkg --get-selections | grep sodium
 [no output]
 $> find /usr/lib | grep sodium
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/libsodium.so
```

This library seems to be stuck.

```
$> apt-get install libsodium-dev libsodium18
[ok]
$> find /usr -type l -ls | grep sodium
   393054      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           34 Feb  6  2016 /usr/share/doc/libsodium-dev/changelog.Debian.gz -> ../libsodium18/changelog.Debian.gz
   132064      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Feb  6  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so -> libsodium.so.18.0.1
   132056      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           19 Feb  6  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18 -> libsodium.so.18.0.1
$> find /usr/lib | grep sodium
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.18.0.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libsodium.pc
/usr/lib/php5/20131226/libsodium.so
```

But after this the PHP error is the same. Grepping files and readlinks in `/etc` and `/usr` hasn't enlightened me about why PHP wants the path containing `20151012` (a YMD date?)

Why is PHP stuck looking in the wrong path for libsodium?

Answer (score 0):

libsodium was installed via pecl which wasn't up-to-date.

```
pecl uninstall libsodium
apt-get install php5-dev
pecl install libsodium
```